# Is there a good way to run Tensorflow on Cloud Functions? Especially when called occasionally

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-functions

I read articles related to TensorFlow2.0

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/how-to-serve-deep-learning-models-using-tensorflow-2-0-with-cloud-functions

and set up a program to perform inference using TensorFlow2.0 on the Google Cloud Functions (Python) environment.

However, I noticed that it would take a long time to start a function from a state where there was no call for about half a day.

I checked and found that the time-consuming part was the import part of TensorFlow. Approximately 20 seconds are consumed.
In the tested code, it is estimated to be around 20 seconds from the time when the print function was output.

```
import logging
print('imported:logging')
import numpy as np
print('imported:numpy')
import tensorflow as tf
print('imported:tensorflow')
```

This means that if i have a small number of users, such as when starting a new service, the first caller within a certain period may time out or require a lot of waiting time. This is especially true for services with optional AI-related functions.

I can come up with measures such as running automatic calls regularly and always warming up, but this is not a good idea.
Is there any other good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you 2 solutions for improving the performance

- Either use a function with 2Gb of memory (if it's not yet the case) for having the vCPU maximum speed (2.4Ghz) and trying to increase performance like this. (The tutorial example set the memory to 2Gb, it was just in case where you have changed this)
- Wrap your function `handler(request)` into a simple Flask server, deploy it on App Engine standard with [warmup endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuring-warmup-requests). You can keep your instance always up. [With Automatic scalling, you have 28 free instance-hour per day](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed). If you have few request, only 1 instance will be up, and you will pay nothing for a low latency prediction service.

Comment: Thank you! I will change it to use AppEngine.
I tried a 800Mhz-2Ghz CPU for import but there was no change in speed. However, normal execution speed is improved. Thank you for the advice!